# Getting NullPointerException when trying to get the screen size

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

This is my code in which I'm getting NullPointerException:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.realplay);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(new RealPlayView(this));

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    String str_ScreenSize = "The Android Screen is: "
                + dm.widthPixels
                + " x "
                + dm.heightPixels;

    TextView mScreenSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    mScreenSize.setText(str_ScreenSize);
}
```

The logcat says:

```
11-04 18:26:24.404: E/AndroidRuntime(15324): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 18:26:24.404: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at com.synamegames.stackem.RealPlayActivity.onCreate(RealPlayActivity.java:27)
11-04 18:26:24.404: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-04 18:26:24.404: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-04 18:26:24.404: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    ... 11 more
```

I've tried numerous amounts of other ways to get the screen width and height but none of them work. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is calling `setContentView()` before `super.onCreate()`, this may be line 27.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works fine so problem is somewhere else, try putting Log statements or run it in the debug mode to find where the null pointer is.

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    String str_ScreenSize = "The Android Screen is: "
                + dm.widthPixels
                + " x "
                + dm.heightPixels;
    Log.i("",str_ScreenSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code also:

```
 Display d=((WindowManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
 width=d.getWidth();
 height=d.getHeight();
```